# CakePHP use Library inside Model

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

Our site is multilanguage (for a client). But instead of translate words like "login" in the PO files, we need to extract them from our translations table in the database. This is a client requirement.

I did research in which way I could make a function that is accessible from anywhere (view, controller, etc.). I concluded that the best way was to make a custom Library, because it said it could be used anywhere.

But I can't use it in my model, it gives me the error that I can't use `ClientnameLibrary::translate('login')` on that place. I added the line `App::uses('ClientnameLibrary', 'Lib');` in my model, and tried this in the validate part:

```
'lastname' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => ClientnameLibrary::translate('lastname_validation_error'),
    ),
),
```

Is there a way I can use my custom Library in a model? And if not, what is the best way to translate the validation messages in my model (from the database)?

This is the code I use in controllers/views:

```
App::uses('ClientnameLibrary', 'Lib'); //include at top of file
echo ClientnameLibrary::translate('login'); //to get translated word from database
```

Comment: "_I can't use it_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific as to what exactly the problem is. That being said, `App::uses()` works fine in models too.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I edited my answer and give the code that I was trying to get working.

Comment: Did you try App::uses('ClientnameLibrary', 'Lib'); in your model file?

Comment: Yes i used the two lines at the end of my question. I will edit my question to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the DB translations [in a po file](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) when the translations change. Without caching, reading every translation with a new query is silly, so you will have to cache it any way. So just turn the DB content into a po file and use the standard translation functions from CakePHP?

Check how the i18n shell extracts the translation strings into pot (NOT po) files. You could probably override the shell to update your DB with the required identifiers as well.

Comment: We are indeed caching the translations from the database.

But how can you save the database translations into a PO/POT file? From what I read I didn't understand that it was possible, and if it is possible, how it is done. Could you maybe provide a link for me?

Comment: I already provided the link that describes the po file. https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html It shouldn't be a problem to write these files, I might be wrong but if you look at a po file it's a very simple format. There are libs as well, for example this one https://github.com/raulferras/PHP-po-parser just search for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked your link. I will give that a try, and thanks for the lib example!